# I've got hardcoded paths in my Makefile - how to use ocamlfind to eliminate those? (or how to use ocamlbuild or omake instead)

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild, omake, ocamlfind

I'm trying to build an ocaml project which requires a camlp4 extension (pa_deriving in this case).  Here's my Makefile:

```
include ./Makefile.config

OCAMLC     := ${OCAMLFIND} ocamlc
OCAMLOPT   := ${OCAMLFIND} ocamlopt
OCAMLDEP   := ${OCAMLFIND} ocamldep
PP         := -package camlp4 -ppopt /home/p/godi-3.12.1.0/lib/ocaml/site-lib/deriving-ocsigen/pa_deriving.cma -syntax camlp4o
LIBS       := -I /home/p/godi-3.12.1.0/lib/ocaml/site-lib/deriving-ocsigen  -package unix -package oUnit

OCAMLFLAGS   = -w Aef

SOURCES = logic.ml          \
      fsm.ml            \
      test_logic.ml         


 test_logic: ${SOURCES:.ml=.cmo}
  ${OCAMLC} -o $@ ${LIBS} -linkpkg deriving.cma $^

 # Common rules

 %.cmi: %.mli
  ${OCAMLC} ${OCAMLFLAGS} ${PP} ${LIBS} -c $<
 %.cmo: %.ml
  ${OCAMLC} ${OCAMLFLAGS} ${PP} ${LIBS} -c $<
 %.cmx: %.ml
  ${OCAMLOPT} ${OCAMLFLAGS} ${PP} ${LIBS} -c $<

 # Clean up
 clean:
  -rm -f *.cm[ioax] *.cmxa *.cmxs *${OBJEXT} *${LIBEXT} *.annot
  -rm -f tests${EXEEXT}
 distclean: clean
  -rm -f *~ \#* .\#*

 # Dependencies
 depend:
   ${OCAMLDEP} ${PP} *.ml *.mli > .depend

 -include .depend
```

This Makefile works; it gets the job done, but the problem is that I've got hardcoded paths above, like: /home/p/godi-3.12.1.0/lib/ocaml/site-lib/deriving-ocsigen/pa_deriving.cma which refers to my godi installation of OCaml.  I want to get rid of those so that I can distribute the code & Makefile so anyone can build with it.

Should I be using omake or ocamlbuild for this?  I'd like to use omake and I've played with an OMakefile for this, but couldn't get anything working - any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update: I tried to use ocamlbuild with the following _tags file:

```
<*.ml>: package(unix), package(oUnit), package(deriving-ocsigen.syntax), syntax(camlp4o)
```

using the following ocamlbuild command: 
    ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind test_logic.native -classic-display

And I get:

```
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamldep -package deriving-ocsigen.syntax -package oUnit -package unix -syntax camlp4o -modules fsm.ml > fsm.ml.depends  
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamldep -package deriving-ocsigen.syntax -package oUnit -package unix -syntax camlp4o -modules logic.ml > logic.ml.depends  
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package deriving-ocsigen.syntax -package oUnit -package unix -syntax camlp4o -o logic.cmo logic.ml 
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package deriving-ocsigen.syntax -package oUnit -package unix -syntax camlp4o -o fsm.cmo fsm.ml  
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -package deriving-ocsigen.syntax -package oUnit -package unix -syntax camlp4o -o logic.cmx logic.ml  
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -package deriving-ocsigen.syntax -package oUnit -package unix -syntax camlp4o -o fsm.cmx fsm.ml  
/home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -linkpkg logic.cmx fsm.cmx   test_logic.cmx -o test_logic.native  
+ /home/phil/godi-3.12.1.0/bin/ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -linkpkg logic.cmx fsm.cmx test_logic.cmx -o test_logic.native  
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:  
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:  
         Deriving_Show referenced from test_logic.cmx  
         Deriving_Enum referenced from test_logic.cmx  
         OUnit referenced from test_logic.cmx
```

What would I need to add to the _tags file to correct this?

Answer (score 3):

I see that you solved your solution with `ocamlbuild`, which is
fine. In the general case, you can use `ocamlfind query` from your
scripts/Makefile as a command-line interface to query information
about findlib packages, and in particular avoid hardcoded path.

```
$ ocamlfind query deriving-ocsigen 
/usr/lib/ocaml/deriving-ocsigen
$ ocamlfind query deriving-ocsigen -i-format
-I /usr/lib/ocaml/deriving-ocsigen
$ ocamlfind query deriving-ocsigen -predicates byte -a-format
deriving_num.cma
$ ocamlfind query deriving-ocsigen.syntax -predicates syntax,preprocessor -a-format
pa_deriving.cma
$ ocamlfind query deriving-ocsigen.syntax -predicates syntax,preprocessor -format "-I %d %a"
-I /usr/lib/ocaml/deriving-ocsigen pa_deriving.cma
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working using ocamlbuild.  Here is the secret sauce:

_tags file:

```
<*.ml> or "test_logic.native": package(unix), package(oUnit), package(deriving-ocsigen), package(deriving-ocsigen.syntax), syntax(camlp4o)
```

**NOTE**: the *or "test_logic.native"* is very important for the linking phase.

Then run:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind test_logic.native -classic-display
```

So I'll probably stick with this ocamlbuild solution.  If anyone knows how to get this going in omake it would be great to see the answer for that as well.